# JS Keycode on OS X : "Digit6" is not triggered when "Space" + another key are already pressed

Tags: javascript, macos, keycode

**"Digit6"** is not triggered when **"Space"** (or **"Slash"**, **"KeyH"** and maybe others) + another random key (let's say "Digit5") are already pressed.

Example with https://keycode.info:

1. Maintaining (**SpaceBar** + **key 5**) and pressing **key 4** returns event.code **"Digit4"**
2. Maintaining (**SpaceBar** + **key 5**) and pressing **key 6** still returns event.code **"Digit5"** (so nothing happens).

I tried this test in Chrome, Safari, Firefox and the results are the same. I've also tried it on Windows 10 and it works as expected so I guess it may be an OS X thing.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a complete answer here just in case someone else comes across this, but for your specific issue, take a look at the end.

The [`KeyboardEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) has a few different properties that can help you find out which keys are pressed:

- ✏️ [`e.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) and [`e.code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) are the new properties that refer to the key that has just been pressed/released.
- [`e.which`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which), [`e.keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) and [`e.charCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/charCode) are the old deprecated properties that were used for the same thing, but should not be used anymore (except if you need to [support really old browsers](https://caniuse.com/keyboardevent-key) for some reason).
- ️ [`altKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/altKey), [`ctrlKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/ctrlKey), [`metaKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/metaKey), [`shiftKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/shiftKey) indicate if the the <kbd>⌥</kbd>, <kbd>⌃</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd> or <kbd>⇧</kbd> keys, respectively, were pressed together with the main key (`e.key` / `e.code`), assuming this one was pressed **before**.

  That means that if you press <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> (in this order), then you'll get `{ e.key: "J", e.shiftKey: true }` in the second event (you get one per key) but if you press <kbd>J</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> (in this order), then you'll get `{ e.key: "J", e.shiftKey: false }` followed by `{ e.key: "Shift", e.shiftKey: true }`.

These are all the properties it contains when pressing <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>:

```
{
    altKey: false, ️
    bubbles: true,
    cancelBubble: false,
    cancelable: true,
    charCode: 0, 
    code: "KeyJ", ✏️
    composed: true,
    ctrlKey: false, ️
    currentTarget: null,
    defaultPrevented: false,
    detail: 0,
    eventPhase: 0,
    isComposing: false,
    isTrusted: true,
    key: "J", ✏️
    keyCode: 74, 
    location: 0,
    metaKey: false, ️
    path: (5) [input#input, body, html, document, Window],
    repeat: false,
    returnValue: true,
    shiftKey: true, ️
    sourceCapabilities: InputDeviceCapabilities { firesTouchEvents: false },
    srcElement: input#input,
    target: input#input,
    timeStamp: 10280.554999997548,
    type: "keydown",
    view: Window { … },
    which: 74, 
}
```

If you go to https://keyjs.dev (**disclaimer: I'm the author.**) you'll see it actually detects any key plus the 4 modifier keys pressed at the same time, as you can see below:

[image: Key.js \ JavaScript KeyboardEvent's key codes & key identifiers]

If you open the console, you can see the individual `KeyboardEvents` being logged.

The problem is that the `KeyboardEvent` only contains information about the last key that has been pressed or released (with the exception of the 4 modifier keys), and both https://keyjs.dev and https://keycode.info log one event at a time, so you need to keep track of what has been pressed/released yourself using the [`keydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event) and [`keyup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keyup_event) events:

```js
const pressedKeys = {};

function logPressedKeys() {
  console.log(Object.keys(pressedKeys).join(' + '));
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', ({ key, altKey, ctrlKey, metaKey, shiftKey }) => {
  pressedKeys[key] = true;
  
  if (altKey) pressedKeys.Alt = true;
  if (ctrlKey) pressedKeys.Control = true;
  if (metaKey) pressedKeys.Meta = true;
  if (shiftKey) pressedKeys.Shift = true;
  
  logPressedKeys();
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', ({ key, altKey, ctrlKey, metaKey, shiftKey }) => {
  delete pressedKeys[key];
  
  if (!altKey) delete pressedKeys.Alt;
  if (!ctrlKey) delete pressedKeys.Control;
  if (!metaKey) delete pressedKeys.Meta;
  if (!shiftKey) delete pressedKeys.Shift;
  
  logPressedKeys();
});
```

Note there's also a hardware limit on how many keys your keyboard can detect while pressed at the same time. In my case, that's 6. However, some keyboard might have a lower limit or encode keys differently, having a lower or higher limit depending on the specific combination of keys, so you might be running on one of those scenarios.